# Add a tool-tip on the text angular text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I am using `text-angular` directive for showing the content. Now, When user hovers on some text I want to show a tool-tip over there,.

```
       <div text-angular id="htmlEditorId" ng-class="totalOrphans == 0 ? 'add-heightTo-textEditor' : 'html-editor-container'" class="textcontent-modal"
                            spellcheck="false" ng-model="data.htmlDocument" ta-disabled="isEditingDisabled" ng-mouseup="doSomethingWithSelectedText($event)"
                            ng-onkeyup="doSomethingWithSelectedText($event)" name="editor1">
                        </div>
 <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
```

I tried with the `ng-mouseover` method and tried to add a tooltip

```
$scope.show_Tool_Tip_OnHover = function(event) {
          if(event.target.nodeName === "SPAN"){
            $scope.show_tool_tip = true;
          } else {
            $scope.show_tool_tip = false;
          }
        }
```

Now, But I don't see any tooltip when hover on the text. Directive is ->

```
textangular
```

Can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see ng-mouseover function initiated on the div element to trigger the show_Tool_Tip_OnHover function which is defined with the scope.

Better to declare a title attribute to the div and assign the required content to it. So, naturally it will show you the browser default tooltip without writing any extra code and its also safe.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3

```
<div text-angular 
    id="htmlEditorId" 
    ng-class="totalOrphans == 0 ? 'add-heightTo-textEditor' : 'html-editor-container'" 
    class="textcontent-modal"
    spellcheck="false" ng-model="data.htmlDocument" 
    ta-disabled="isEditingDisabled" 
    name="editor1" 
    title="Tooltip text">
</div>
```